# Find First Match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables that look roughly like this (only including relevant info):

```
------------ Master --------------
ID | Master_Number | First_Arrival
```

```
---------- Vehicle ------------
ID | Master_ID | Name | Arrived
```

In the above, `Vehicle.Master_ID` is a FK to `Master.ID`

I've created a table variable like this:

```
declare @foo table (Master_Number varchar(20), First_Arrival datetime, Name varchar(20), Arrived datetime)

insert into
@foo
select
    M.Master_Number,
    M.First_Arrival,
    V.Name,
    V.Arrived
from
    Master as M
inner join
    Vehicle as V
on
    V.Master_ID = I.ID
order by M.Master_Number, V.Arrived
```

This gives me a nice list of all vehicles related to the same Master_Number, and the order they arrived in.

What I'm attempting to do is get something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------- Result --------------------------------------------------
Master_Number | First_Arrival | Vehicle_1_Name | Vehicle_1_Arrived | Vehicle_2_Name | Vehicle_2_Arrived
```

sorted where `Vehicle_1_Arrived < Vehicle_2_Arrived`, `Vehicle_1_Name like '[ETL]%'`, and `'Vehicle_2_Name like '[TL]%'`

The problem I'm running into is that there may be zero or more vehicles associated with a `Master_ID`, and I only want each row to be the first results that match this exactly, disregarding any other vehicles related to that `Master_ID`, and any `null` values.

I'm new to SQL, and can't wrap my head around this....any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if there are more than two vehicles?

Comment: In that case, I would want the vehicle with the first arrived time with `name like ‘[ETL]%’`, and the second vehicle with the second arrived time and `name like ‘[TL]%’, ignoring all others and any null values.

Comment: If any vehicles arrive between or after the two I’m looking for, they can be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very good candidate for `apply`:

```
select M.Master_Number, M.First_Arrival, v1.Name, v1.Arrived,
       v1.Name, v2.Arrived
from Master m cross apply
     (select top (1) v1.*
      from Vehicle v1
      where v.Master_ID = I.ID and v1.Name like '[ETL]%'
      order by v1.arrived
     ) v1 cross apply
     (select top (1) v2.*
      from Vehicle v2
      where v2.Master_ID = I.ID and v2.Name like '[TL]%' and
            v2.arrived > v1.arrived
      order by v2.arrived asc
     ) v2
order by M.Master_Number;
```

`apply` implements a lateral join, which is a lot like a correlated subquery, except it can return multiple columns and/or multiple rows.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you! I hadn't come across `apply` or `cross apply` yet, so I've got something to read up on!

Comment: Now I’m curious...how would this problem be solved if `apply` wasn’t an option?

Comment: @forgot . . . You can ask another question.  It would be more challenging.